# JSP database access not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I am trying to retrieve mysql data in a jsp page.The problem I am facing is the retrieved values are not getting printed. But hello is printed correctly based on number of rows in the table

The code is

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <%@page import="java.sql.*,javax.servlet.*,javax.sql.*" %>
  <%

      //Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      //Open a connection
         Connection conn=null;
         conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/quiz","root","root");
        // Execute SQL query
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql="select Question_Id,Question from question_master;";
        out.println(sql);
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql); 
        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println("hello");
            int id=rs.getInt("Question_Id");
            String ques=rs.getString("Question");
            System.out.println("ID: " + id + "<br>");
            System.out.println("Question " + ques+ "<br>");
        }
      %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you are writing

```
System.out.println("ID: " + id + "<br>");
            System.out.println("Question " + ques+ "<br>");
```

which will print in server console

you have to write

```
out.println("ID: " + id + "<br>");
            out.println("Question " + ques+ "<br>");
```

to print in jsp page